# Validating the XML with local DTD, throws error

Tags: java, xml, dom, dtd, saxparser

I am trying to validate my XML with local DTD, I did google about this then I got some code, here is my code.

```
public Document buildDocument(File receivedFile) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        logger.info("Inside buildDocument() , create a new DocumentBuilderFactory");
        // create a new DocumentBuilderFactory
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(true);
        // use the factory to create a documentbuilder
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.err.println("fatalError: " + exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.err.println("error: " + exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
                System.err.println("warning: " + exception);
            }
        });

        builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
                if (systemId.contains("xyz.com/remote.dtd")) {
                    return new InputSource(FileUtils.readFileToString(
                            new File("C:\\Users\\xyz\\local.dtd"));
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(FileUtils.readFileToString(receivedFile, "UTF-16"))));
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Opps got error while buiding document", e);
    }
    return doc;
```

I am getting following error, I am sure the local DTD works fine with the XML which I am trying to validate. I don't find any issue with DTD but still I get this error please help on this.

```
> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <!DOCTYPE ichicsr [
> <!ENTITY lt     "&#38;#60;">
> 
> <!-- Greater Than ">" --> <!ENTITY gt     "&#62;"> 
> 
> <!-- Ampersand "&" --> <!ENTITY amp    "&#38;#38;">
```

Prints the entire DTD then!

```
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:964)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:902)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:869)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:241)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1001)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:875)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:798)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:230)
```

> NOTE : My XML is encoded type UTF-16

Update : Removed UF-16 while reading  the file, looks like DTD is trying to get compile and it's throwing me following error ,

> latin-entities.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)

Does it mean is this DTD is looking for dependent DTD ??

Comment: file path ? are you asking about the dtd file path ? yes the file is there in the location, and the XML I am receiving from UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is here:

```
if (systemId.contains("xyz.com/remote.dtd")) {
    return new InputSource(FileUtils.readFileToString(
                     new File("C:\\Users\\xyz\\local.dtd"));
```

Assuming here that the `FileUtils.readFileToString()` returns the file content as a
string.

The XMLEntityManager expects the InputSource to supply a system Id as a URL, but it will get the file content instead, hence the MalformedURLException.

Either create an InputSource based on the URL of the file

```
new InputSource(new File(...).toURI().toASCIIString()
```

or create the InputSource with a StringReader over the file content

```
new InputSource(new StringReader(FileUtils....))
```